# Firebase Real-time database rules. Задать права без @uid

Tags: vue.js, firebase, firebase-database, spa, rules

Таблица с тасками (корневая) сортируются по ключу. Также у всех тасков есть поле юзер, которое содержит uid пользователя, который ее добавлял.

Нужно сделать так, чтобы пользователь имел права read & write только на те таски, которые он создавал. **То есть нужно задать правила в котором будет проверка поле юзер на соотвествие с auth.uid**

Важно то, что в пути к таскам нету параметра с пользователем, поэтому простое правило

```
  "tasks": {
   "$uid": {
     ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
     ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }
 }
```

не сработает и обычная проверка на логин =! нулл тоже

*и можно ли как-то в файр бейс привязать определенный домен, чтобы именно с него принимались все запросы?*

[image: проблема]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Как я понял выход только один:
example.com/tasks/-LPqa516TxYFFw-JJOQi

```
  "tasks": {
   "$uid": {
     ".read": "$uid === auth.uid",
     ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"
   }
 }
```